# Simplify file path from "find"

Tags: find

Currently I'm trying to find some files using the `find` command.

```
find -wholename "./blah/*.mp4"
```

This returns:

```
./blah/blah2/a.mp4
./blah/blah2/b.mp4
```

Is there any way I can simplify the output of this so that it only returns `blah/blah2/a.mp4` without the beginning two characters (being `./`)?

Comment: Why not just use `find blah/ -name '*.mp4'`.

Comment: @Thomas That makes for an answer, do you mind adding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` controls.

```
find -wholename "./blah/*.mp4" -printf "%P\n"
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess the only other question would be how do I pass that into the find -exec parameter? If I use the standard {} to represent the name, it still returns the full path (with ./) instead.